# Use curly braces instead of brackets for Terraform list

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, terraform, kubernetes-helm

I want to install the official `jenkins` helm [chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/jenkins/) using Terraform which then invokes Ansible.

Ideally, I would use the Terraform `helm` provider but it has a [severe](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-helm/issues/389) [limitation](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-helm/issues/281) when [being](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-helm/issues/355) [invoked](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-helm/issues/385) over [tls](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/error-with-helm-provider-using-tls/).

Therefore I am performing the actual `helm` installation via the following `local-exec` installation.

```
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "ansible-playbook -vvv ${path.module}/playbooks/playbook.yaml -i ./playbooks/hosts --extra-vars \"{ \"k8s_cluster_name\": \"${local.k8s_name}\", \"zonename\": \"${var.zone}\", \"env_name\": \"${var.env_name}\", \"google_project_name\": \"${var.project_id}\", \"jenkins_master_image_tag\": \"${var.jenkins_master_image_tag}\", \"jenkins_agent_image_tag\": \"${var.jenkins_agent_image_tag}\", \"jenkins_plugins_list\": \"${var.jenkins_plugins_list}\" }\""
  }
}
```

My purpose is to be able to pass the plugins list used in the values file as argument (i.e. extra var) to `ansible` cmd.

Therefore I declared the following var:

```
variable "jenkins_plugins_list" {
  description = "The list of jenkins' plugins to be installed"
  type = "list"
  default = ["kubernetes:1.21.2", "workflow-job:2.36", "workflow-aggregator:2.6", "credentials-binding:1.20", "git:4.0.0"]
}
```

The particular `ansible` task that will use the `jenkins_plugins_list` variable is the following:

```
    - name: Install Jenkins
      register: jenkins_init
      shell: "helm upgrade --force --tls --install --set master.installPlugins={{ jenkins_plugins_list }}  --set master.tag={{ jenkins_master_image_tag }} --set agent.tag={{ jenkins_agent_image_tag }} -f {{ tempdir }}/{{ env_name }}-jenkins/jenkins-values.yaml jenkins-{{ env_name }} --namespace jenkins stable/jenkins"
      retries: 5
      delay: 30
      until: jenkins_init.rc == 0
```

I am trying to explicitly set the [`master.installPlugins`](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/jenkins/values.yaml#L215) variable via the tf variable passed during the ansible invocation.

The problem is the following:

The `helm` command accepts the list i.e. the value corresponding to the variable `jenkins_plugins_list` as follows:

```
helm upgrade --force --tls --install --set master.installPlugins="{kubernetes:1.21.2,git:4.0.0}"
```

i.e. with quotes and curly braces.

However I have only managed to produce the following output:

```
helm upgrade --force --tls --install --set master.installPlugins=[u'kubernetes:1.21.2', u'workflow-job:2.36', u'workflow-aggregator:2.6', u'credentials-binding:1.20', u'git:4.0.0'] -f /org_files/tmp/myenv-jenkins/jenkins-values.yaml jenkins-myenv --namespace jenkins stable/jenkins"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the list as a... list, which is a good thing ;)

You need to transform that to "whatever that format is" you need, which is the list of element separated by comas and surrounded by curly braces.

See the below example. Syntax is a little tricky to bypass the triple curly braces in the expression that cause an interpretation error:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    jenkins_plugins_list: ['kubernetes:1.21.2', 'workflow-job:2.36', 'workflow-aggregator:2.6', 'credentials-binding:1.20', 'git:4.0.0']

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ '{' + jenkins_plugins_list | join(',') + '}' }}"
```

Which gives

```
PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "{kubernetes:1.21.2,workflow-job:2.36,workflow-aggregator:2.6,credentials-binding:1.20,git:4.0.0}"
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```